# How often are poster presentations rejected from conferences?

Tags: conference, rejection, poster

I've never given any sort of presentation at a conference before, but I was under the impression that poster presentations are less prestigious and also much easier to get accepted.

I submitted a late abstract in the second round call for "late breaking" posters. I will hear back supposedly by the end of the week whether the abstract has been accepted or rejected.

The abstract is definitely on-topic for the conference (it's a very large, general applied math conference with multiple sessions in various subfields, but the poster session is for all applied math fields). My PI/advisor is very well-known within my field. We worked on the project together, although I would be the one presenting the poster if it gets accepted. She read over the abstract and helped make corrections/suggestions as well.

Just wondering generally how often a poster presentation would be rejected in this case.

Comment: You know what the problem is here: there is no information on what quality other posters are of. Hence, there is no way for anyone to tell. Just wait patiently. And best of luck! :)

Comment: An excerpt from [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/how-important-are-poster-sessions-in-conferences/2631#2631) by @gerrit to a [related question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/how-important-are-poster-sessions-in-conferences/): "In my field, posters are not peer-reviewed and virtually always accepted, if not clearly off-topic or rejected for political reasons."

Comment: In my area (circuits and systems) posters are claimed to be as prestigious as lecture presentations (and there are no separate calls). However, in practice the "worse" part of the accepted papers (~45% of all submitted papers are accepted for the major conference) are typically assigned to poster presentation. But they are accepted as full contributions and you can not tell from data bases if it was a poster or a lecture presentation afterwards. This seems to be common practice in many adjacent electrical engineering fields as well.

Comment: In physics, typically none are rejected.  At some conferences, no talks are rejected either.

Comment: Impossible to tell. Contributions are rejected if the submitted abstract is horribly bad and/or off topic. Otherwise the venue is filled with the best contributions or eventually more sessions are added. A rather good contribution might be rejected or downgraded to poster if the space is just full. An extended deadline for submission however means there is still space,

Answer (score 4):

In my field (Electrical Engineering), poster and oral presentations are usually accompanied by a full paper submission (or atleast an extended abstract) which is what is peer-reviewed, so the acceptance ratio of posters would be the same as that of the oral presentations.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the conference and the field. Some conferences have limited space for posters and there is plenty of submissions for those slots, so some percentage are rejected.  Other conference have space for all submitted posters.

Mainly, you should view posters as opportunities to meet other researchers, and to practice your skills in presenting your research and answering questions.  It also often is a requirement to get school or department funding to pay for your conference expenses.

Answer (score 0):

In my field it is rare for a competent poster abstract to be rejected. There are only so many places for talks, so that can be selective. I sometimes prefer to present certain pieces of work as a poster because the opportunities for discussion are better, and it allows my students to talk about their work instead of having me do it. Posters are not automatically considered bad.

Comment: It would be good if you specified what your field is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it really depends on your field and your conference organizer.

As a poster reviewer, I did reject some posters (around 2%), but they were really poorly written (I can't understand their English), the study did not make sense (poor methodology) or it is totally irrelevant to the conference theme. While it may seem the rejection rate is low, remember that usually people who submit poster are graduate student with their supervisors as second author, so there are some quality control before they are submitted for review, and that could partly be the reason why most poster got accepted. After all, poster is more like preliminary finding sharings and conference is for exchange of ideas, as long as the idea make sense, I see no reason to reject them.

But I heard some conference is really just a business and they got their money from people presenting poster, so they may accept anything...