# How to prepare poster paper for conference that rejected full paper

Tags: conference, rejection, poster

I received a paper reject for a full paper (10 pages) submission in one of the top conferences in CS (distributed systems). I agree with some of the critical remarks, but we felt they should be considered as "extensions" of the work rather than deficiencies in our work. I also felt that the reviewers were not as familiar with this new reasearch area (always seems like the case!). I was planning to extend the work and look for another conference 2-3 months down the road.

Meanwhile, the same conference has started a poster track and "invited" us to submit a poster paper (3 pages) for the same. I am debating whether and how to go about it. I used to be under an impression that posters are "less" important than paper talks, but after reading this ([How important are poster sessions in conferences?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/how-important-are-poster-sessions-in-conferences/75956#75956)), and discussing with colleagues, I feel this could be a good opportunity to discuss with the research community, polish the work and then extend the work (with new / existing remarks) and submit for a journal. Extending a full conference paper into a journal is reasonably common practice in our lab, especially for papers that go in thesis.

Considering I have plans to publish a longer paper eventually, how should I go about preparing this 3-page (IEEE 2-column) "poster paper"? Shall I keep it more textual and keep the model / results in the poster? Or put the model with preliminary results in paper and all extra material in poster?

I checked with the conference that this 3 page paper gets published and not the poster. Any general guidance?

Comment: This is not an answer but a remark about short papers. Usually big conferences invite the authors of rejected papers (borderline) to submit them as short papers without going through the review process. Be aware that your paper might be sent to the same reviewers and if they strongly rejected your previous paper due to technical problems, it is less likely to accept it as a short paper.

Comment: Usually people submit to workshops held under the name of the conference after a rejection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been involved in a number of conferences that offer posters to rejected papers as well as other newer work that wasn't ready or acceptable as a full paper.  Usually they don't publish short papers in a proceedings, though some do, as in this case.  I think presenting a poster is indeed a good way to get your work out into the community and get feedback.

The poster is not usually "reviewed" in the usual sense and the bar is typically pretty low.  So if the conference said "this might make a good poster" then it probably will.

> Considering I have plans to publish a longer paper eventually, how should I go about preparing this 3-page (IEEE 2-column) "poster paper"? Shall I keep it more textual and keep the model / results in the poster? Or put the model with preliminary results in paper and all extra material in poster?

Regarding the question of what to put into the paper, I suspect some may want to close this question as depending on personal circumstances, but I will try and give more general suggestions.   I would not recommend putting results in the poster and not the paper.  That seems wrong to me.  Just like with a full-length paper, the paper and the presentation should be roughly in sync.

I'm not clear on what "all extra material" refers to.

In general, treat your poster as an advertisement for the work and for people to read the paper (even if it's abbreviated).  There should be more material in the paper than the poster, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks Fred. "There should be more material in the paper than the poster, not the other way around" clears it up for me. So I should keep model, results and infereneces in the short-paper, and add some of the eye-catchy "motivation" and "why is it important" in the poster.